# Is there way to influence AlchemyAPI sentiment analysis

Tags: sentiment-analysis, alchemyapi

I was using AlchemyAPI for text analysis. I want to know if there is way to influence the API results or fine-tune it as per the requirement.

I was trying to analyse different call center conversations available on internet. To understand the sentiments i.e. whether customer was unsatisfied/angry and hence conversation is negative.

For 9 out of 10 conversations it gave sentiment as positive and for 1 it was negative. That conversation was about emergency response system (#911 in US).  It seems that words shooting, fear, panic, police, siren could have cause this result.

But actually the whole conversation was fruitful. Caller was not angry with the service instead call center person solved the caller's problem and caller was relaxed. So logically this should not be treated as negative.

What is the way ahead to customize the AlchemyAPI behavior ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are currently looking at the tools that would be required to allow customization of the AlchemyAPI services. Our current service is entirely pre-trained on billions of web pages, but customization is on the road map. I can't give you any timelines this early, but keep checking back!

Zach, Dev Evangelist AlchemyAPI

Comment: Thanks @zach. I will look out for this customization. Any guess when it can be available. Also whenever it is available will you be able to update it in this thread ?