# Algorithms behind the Alchemy API for concept and keywords extraction

Tags: algorithm, nlp, text-mining, text-analysis, alchemyapi

I've started using the alchemy API but I would like to know if
there is any scientific publication that explains the models used for extracting the keywords and the concepts from the text?

Also according to this answer [Is there way to influence AlchemyAPI sentiment analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30954978/is-there-way-to-influence-alchemyapi-sentiment-analysis?rq=1)
the models used for  the alchemy Api were trained on billions of web pages. My question is on which type of data the algorithms were trained on
(only news content for example?).

Thank you in advance for the answers.

Comment: I would like to know too but they're not open sourced =(

Answer (score 1):

Their website says that AlchemyAPI uses a deep learning model. Other than that tidbit, they keep their secret sauce under wraps.

Now that they've been acquired by IBM, their APIs are part of IBM's Bluemix suite of machine learning services. There is a way to train the model using your own data. The custom model option is not cheap though: $3,500.00 USD/Custom Model Instance per Month, in addition to API request charges.

If you want an open-source alternative try [DatumBox](http://www.datumbox.com/). It's open-source, and you can dig in as deep as you'd like.